# Binary to struct in c

Tags: c, struct, binary

Im reading from a text file and a binary file and each line of the binary file is associated to each line of the text file. Im using fread to read my binary file info to a struct but now i want to print each line of the text file with the associated binary info this is my code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int vetorInteiros[6];
    char vetorCaracteres[6];
}Registos_Binario;
int ler_informacao_total(char *FichLimpo, char *FichBinario, Registos_Binario *vetor_estruturas)
{
    char classeChave[500][500];
    char classesValor[500];
    int comprimento_mapa = 0;
    

    FILE *fB = fopen(FichBinario, "rb");

    if(fB == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nao fo possivel encontrar o ficheiro.\n");

        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 345; i++)
    {
        fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, 6, 1, fB);
        
        fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorCaracteres, 6, 1, fB);

        fseek(fB, 2, SEEK_CUR);

                
    }
    fclose(fB);
    
}
int main()
{
    char escolha;

    char nomeficheirosujo[100];
    char nomefhicheirolimpo[100];
    char nomeficheirobinario[100];

    Registos_Binario vetor_estruturas[345];
```

I have tried to print inside my loop with pointrs to the vectores inside my struct but its not the same info as the binary file.

Comment: btw i dindt put all my main fuction but i call the ler_informacao_total function

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question, not in comments. Also, Using useful (English) names and comments in your code increases readability for most SO users

Comment: "each line of the binary file" What do you consider a "line" in a binary file? Binary files are not line oriented.

Comment: How were the structures *saved* to the file? As the whole structure, or member by member (like you try to read it)?

Comment: Also don't forget to return something from your function when reading was successful (which you don't really check).

Comment: @Gerhardh That was my thought too. "Each line" makes no sense for a binary file.

Comment: "I have tried...but its not the same info as the binary file." Please show what you have tried. Your code does not contain any text file. Also, do you expect to have both files hold same information? Keeping same data twice is more work, at best or a source of errors and inconsistencies at worst.

Comment: `fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, 6, 1, fB);` This looks very fishy. You read into an array of 6 integer elements. Depending on what you stored in the file, it should probable be `fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, sizeof int, 6, fB);`

Comment: An advice is to translate variables to english. There is a reason why variable names like "a", "b" is discouraged, but those give me just as much info as your variables.

Comment: Your code is quite obscure and quite problematic -- there's no chance it would work for, well, whatever you're trying to accomplish here (I have no clue and judging by others's comments, I don't think anyone understood what you are trying to do. 

As mentioned, it's hard to tell something about how you read the data without knowing how you wrote them into your file. But please, remember, integer sizes change across architectures, so if you want a portable binary file, use a more structured format (and in no architecture at all an integer has only 1 byte).

Comment: Also, people NEED TO STOP using typedefs for structs. I know people think it's "cool" or something, but it actually makes the code less readable and is a terrible practice, because when you see in your code a variable of type `struct Registos_Binario` you know it's a struct, but when you see a variable of type `Registos_Binario` you don't know what is that and whether it's a struct, a union, an enum, an integer, etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh, supposing that it's an error for the destination array to be only partially read, I would be more inclined to go with `fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, 6 * sizeof(int), 1, fB);`  Or perhaps `fread(&vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, sizeof vetor_estruturas[i].vetorInteiros, 1, fB);`. (Also, the `sizeof`'s operand needs to be parenthesized when it is a type name.)

Comment: You say you're reading from a text file *and* a binary file, but your code reads everything from the same (binary) file.  The binary *vs*. text distinction is about file format, not file semantic contents, so if it is indeed correct to read everything from the same file then (as your code is handling it) your file is a binary one.  We *really* need to know the details of the file format to be able to advise you.  A format specification would be great, but the code used to write the file would be sufficient.